# InvalidStateError html5 webrtc Data channel testing

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc

I am working on webRTC. I got Video calling and Now testing Datachannels but Getting Invalid state error on creating.

```
var pc_config = {
        "iceServers" : [ {
            "url" : "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"
        } ]
    };

    this.peerConn = new RTCPeerConnection(pc_config,{optional: [{RtpDataChannels: true}]});
this.channel=this.peerConn.createDataChannel("DataChannel",{reliable: false});
```

what is the best state to create data channel?
How flow matters?

Comment: Try webrtc data channel oriented simple demos here : https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/demos#chrome-to-chrome-webrtc-data-connection

Comment: any thing wrong in my flow

Comment: First question: Are you using Firefox stable or old Firefox nightly? ....... some changes happened in latest nightly: https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/wiki/WebRTC-DataChannel-and-Firefox ---- if you're using chrome or latest nightly; your coding order seems correct. Process is like this ---- create peer connection --- quickly create data channel ----- then create offer. Can you give a link of demo page?

Comment: I saw your experiment https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/demos#chrome-to-chrome-webrtc-data-connection  I just getting error on initial creation state.

Comment: Try chrome 27 beta or canary.

Comment: I just going through it, I have doubt, when will onicecandidate execute. and can we use same peer connection for video call.